# Software Center and Update Manager GUI, Anthentication failed - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

This is a problem that occurred within the last year after one of the software updates.  I cannot tell when or which update.  Simply put, I can run 'sudo apt...' successfully from the terminal.  Not a password problem.  The GUI update-manager and software-center does not recognize my password.

Comment: "Not a password problem" and "does not recognize my password" seem contradictory.

Comment: The password used is correct.  It logs me in.  It works with sudo.  It does not work with aptdaemon.  Far from contradictory.  Configuration problem with aptdaemon? or just a bug in aptdaemon.  This is in ubuntu 20.04.  I can run update-manager from a terminal with root privileges (sudo update-manager).

Comment: When I run "sudo update-manager" in a terminal I have to pass the sudo authentication challenge, but there is no aptdaemon challenge.  The update-manager will run with no authentication challenge from the menu, or from the update notification, until the next reboot.